# Animating the resizing of a boxview proportionally in Xamarin Forms

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, easing

In my shared project I have a need for resizing a `BoxView` at the click of a button. It should preferably switch between taking up no space and 25% of any screen size proportionally, for which I'd usually use `AbsoluteLayout`.

I've tried using `AbsoluteLayout` and `LayoutTo` but since `LayoutTo` operates in pixels I've been unable to resize proportionally.

I've then change my solution to utilize `Grid` and a custom animation as seen in the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimationTest"
             x:Class="AnimationTest.MainPage">
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" x:Name="LeftColumn"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <BoxView Color="DarkMagenta" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>

        <Button Text="Animate" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

and the codebehind

```
namespace AnimationTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        Animation _animation;
        bool _boxCollapsed = false;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (_boxCollapsed)
            {
                case true:
                    _animation = new Animation(
                    (d) => LeftColumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star));
                    _animation.Commit(this, "the animation", 16, 1000, Easing.SinIn, null, null);
                    _boxCollapsed = false;
                    break;
                case false:
                    _animation = new Animation(
                    (d) => LeftColumn.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star));
                    _animation.Commit(this, "the animation", 16, 1000, Easing.SinIn, null, null);
                    _boxCollapsed = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has presented two issues though.

While currently not a problem this solution obviously resizes the entire column and not just the `BoxView` which could potentially become a problem at later stages.
The second issue is that it seems to ignore the `Easing` parameter and just instantly goes between the two widthswithout actually animating.

I'm hoping someone can at the least inform me of what the issue is regarding the `Easing` or come up with a different and hopefully more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll just have to change a little bit the code on the animation line, i already give you hint on how to get the 25% of screen size. Hope it helps.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var twentyFivePercentOfScreen = this.Width * .25;

        switch (_boxCollapsed)
        {
            case true:
                _animation = new Animation(
                    (d) => LeftColumn.Width = d, 0, twentyFivePercentOfScreen);
                _animation.Commit(this, "the animation", 16, 250, Easing.SinIn, null, null);
                _boxCollapsed = false;
                break;
            case false:
                _animation = new Animation(
                    (d) => LeftColumn.Width = d, twentyFivePercentOfScreen, 0);
                _animation.Commit(this, "the animation", 16, 250, Easing.SinIn, null, null);
                _boxCollapsed = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I altered my solution slightly but thanks to your help I managed exactly what I wanted.